# How to solve a double variable Integral that have different limits of Integration.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

In $\triangle$ABC with angles $$\angle BCA=\theta$$$$\angle ABC = \alpha$$ $$\angle BAC=\phi$$
such that $B$ is at the center of a circle $C(O,r)$ and $A$ lies on $C(O,r)$ and $A$ starts from the intersection point of $BC$ and follows the path on $C(O,r)$ till the point of intersection of $CB$ produced and $C(O,r)$ (Sorry for no diagram as I can't find appropriate tool for this).
Now, we have a integral, $$E = \int{\sin{\theta}\sin{\alpha}^2\cdot d\alpha}$$ So from this we can decide the integrating limits of $\sin{\alpha}$ i.e. from 0 to $\pi$ but I can't find the relation
between $\sin{\theta}$ and $\sin{\alpha}$.
So how can I solve this integral.
Note: This is not a homework-exercise question it is the part of a derivation in physics and I am only stuck at this point any hint will help me further out this and I can complete the derivation.
Also I am a high school student so answer the question according to that.